# python run .exe app with argument

Tags: python, command-prompt, senna

If i write this in command prompt: 
"senna-win32.exe < input.txt >output.txt" 
it works perfect but i need to do this from python code, how is this possible?

I have tried:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([pathToExe, "input.txt" , "output.txt"])
```

---

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([pathToExe, '< input.txt > output.txt'])
```

I'm getting error of "invalid argument
 < input.txt > output.txt".

Comment: Please indicate what happened when you tried those things.

Comment: Look closer at the documentation for `subprocess.call`...

Comment: @JackManey are you seeing something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Kevin update with error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Jack!!!

```
import subprocess
myinput = open('in.txt')
myoutput = open('out.txt', 'w')
p = subprocess.Popen('senna-win32.exe', stdin=myinput, stdout=myoutput)
p.wait()
myoutput.flush()
```